# how to send HTTP PUT request via Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP)

Tags: put, owasp

I am kinda new on ZAP, with a simple running i can confirm GET results. But I could not find  any PUT method options to set.
Could you please help me on this, if you know. Please add a pic if possible.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "confirm GET results".  If you are talking about the REST API, then I believe all of the calls use the GET method.  At least the setters and action calls use a GET and return the result.

If you mean attacking using a PUT then you should populate the "Sites" with URLs to attack using a browser to navigate the site with the proxy set, or the spider, which crawls a web site recording possible HTTP requests, that include GET, POST, PUT, etc.  You can see the URLs in the desktop GUI, top left pane.  Once there are URLs in the tree you can run an active scan on those URLs.  It will run a set of known attacks that can may include different HTTP verbs as required.

Some of those attacks may include appropriate verb tampering:

http://www.imperva.com/Resources/Glossary?term=http_verb_tampering